# SSH Server connection issue From Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, server, permissions

I have a following issue while connecting staging server using SSH cmd.

My cmd -> ssh hostaddress

**Error -> root@host: Permission denied (publickey).**

I have setup .ssh folder , and generated keygen keys as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try asking in Superuser.   That said,  ensure you have the correct ssh key permissions *and* that ```root``` is permitted to log in via ssh.

Comment: Also, by using `ssh hostaddress` it is implied `ssh <current_user_in_client_machine>@hostaddress`. You may want to try logging in with a specific username as `ssh <username>@hostaddress`.